# Asp.Net Core 3.0 CreatedAtAction returns "no route matches the supplied values" when Action name ends with "Async"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I had a strange problem with CreatedAtAction, if my method name ends with "Async" keyword, I get an 500 error "no route matches the supplied values" when I return CreatedAtAction from my Add method. If I put anything else as method name like GetRatePlanAs, GetRatePlanAsyncA or GetRatePlan then it works like a charm.

It would also work if I add [ActionName("GetRatePlanAsync")] but I didn't want to do that.

CreatedAtAction:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetRatePlanAsync), new { ... }, null);
```

Doesn't work:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("item")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRatePlanAsync(...)
```

Works:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("item")]
    [ActionName("GetRatePlanAsync")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRatePlanAsync(...)
```

Also work:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("item")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRatePlan(...)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After few hours of testing and stuff, I have found these articles:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15316 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names

In short, that is a breaking change in Asp.Net Core 3.0.

One solution for this that I actually liked was to set options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames to false in Configure Services Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);

        ...
    }
```

Comment: *Strange bug/behavior...*  Yes leaving the "Async" suffix off, or `[ActionName("MyActionNameAsync")]` annotation works (as the OP said).  Or using `options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames ` in Startup.cs works also (work-around given by Nemanja).  Thanks both of you!